# How to pre-process month abbreviation for modelling

Tags: python, dataframe, data-preprocessing

Given the below column:

|  | col |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN |
| 1 | Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct |
| 2 | Jan,Jun,Jul |
| 3 | Apr,May,Oct,Nov |
| 4 | NaN |

How to convert the month abbreviation into integer data that can be fed to the model?

Comment: Please provide desired output and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Would this be on the right path for you? The function is just a look up of the value in a Python dictionary and returns the value if found or None if not.

You can then split the column in each row to get a list of the months.  It's not entirely clear if that's what's required as there is no desired output provided.

```
    def month_to_int(abbreviated_month):
        return {
                'Jan': 1,
                'Feb': 2,
                'Mar': 3,
                'Apr': 4,
                'may': 5,
                'Jun': 6,
                'Jul': 7,
                'Aug': 8,
                'Sep': 9, 
                'Oct': 10,
                'Nov': 11,
                'Dec': 12
        }.get(abbreviated_month)
    
    rows = [
        'NaN',
        'Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct',
        'Jan,Jun,Jul',
        'Apr,May,Oct,Nov',
        'NaN'
    ]
    
    for row in rows:
        print([month_to_int(month) for month in row.split(',')])


    [None]
    [1, 4, 7, 10]
    [1, 6, 7]
    [4, None, 10, 11]
    [None]
```